# KeyError: 'DB_NAME' when doing makemigrations in django

Tags: django, postgresql, makemigrations

I store all my secrets and database params in the dev.env file.
I have 3 different settings files - base, dev and prod.
There is an SQLite database in base, and I want to connect to Postgres in dev.

So I upload my secrets with the environment variable in my dev setting file like this:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(os.environ.get('ENV_CONFIG', ''))
```

And I override my database settings in dev settings file:

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['DB_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASS'],
        'HOST': os.environ['DB_HOST'],
        'PORT': os.environ['DB_PORT'],
    }
}
```

But when I run `makemigrations` with dev settings file:

```
./manage.py makemigrations --settings=app.settings.dev
```

I get an error:

```
File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Programming/Python/UkranianFunds/src/app/settings/dev.py", line 35, in <module>
    'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DB_NAME'
```

I checked and my secret with the key DB_NAME clearly appears in the settings file - I printed it successfully. The name of the database is correct.

What are other reasons that cause that?

Comment: *Where* do you have that `load_dotenv` code…?

Comment: @deceze, in dev setting file

Answer (score 0):

Your loaded dev.env file does not contain 'DB_NAME' as a key.

Comment: No, it contains.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing `os.environ['DB_NAME']` to `os.environ.get('DB_NAME')`.

Weird situation for me because the problem occurred only when I did `makemigrations`.

After I migrated to Postgres, I tried to run the app with `os.environ['DB_NAME']` and it worked fine.

So it seems that the `KeyError` is being raised only during `makemigrations`.